# Is there a point to dependency injection container in Python?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

Been messing about with python, as usual it throws my rigid static typed Object Oriented world in to a bit of a mess. Python supports duck typing, has no usable concept of interface based programming (as in C# interfaces) and allows Global variables. With all these goodies is there really any point to a dependency injection container or does the Python run-time become the container.

I understand the point to these containers in static typed OO languages such as Java and C# but where would such a thing fit into the nutty world of python (I love it)?

I have always suspected that Dependency injection as a design pattern was a bad smell that has been created by everything must be a class "Nazi thinking" that is c# and Java, would i be correct or is there something I am missing?

So far I think I can cover factories, Singletons, Multi-instance objects, just by using Globals. I also suspect that the Aspect stuff is covered too, although I am still thinking about this.

The Duck Typing is the thing that is getting me at the moment, so used to defining interfaces then basing classes on these interfaces and letting the static stuff cover my stupidity that I feel that without static typing, containers are a bit useless.

Comment: sorry @jiggy, I read it, but don't see the relevance. I am coming from a c# background (well recent background), done some java in my time and Delphi. I am trying to reassess all my assumptions and learnings using Static languages and seeing how they come up when doing things dynamic. MVC is a talk for another day :)

Comment: @Jiggy as for Django, I have no idea about it, I like CherryPy for web stuff. its nice and simple. You can control the MVC to your hearts content.

Comment: As for .net, its at the point now where Java was about 6 years ago, floods of frameworks coming out, all claiming to be the latest and greatest and get your work done in half the time. Don't believe the hype.

Comment: I was responding to you observation on "Nazi thinking" in the C#/Java community. I intended it as commentary and not an answer to your main question.

Comment: Python a Nazi language, no way...its all loosey goosey. I think that making everything a class in Java/C# was a bad language design choice made at a time when OO was all the rage without question.

Comment: You're focusing strongly on the fact that static DI frameworks have to wrangle static interfaces here. Another strong advantage DI frameworks can give you is runtime implementation selection, since it decouples instantiation/dependency selection from the code that relies on those dependencies. If your "composition root" (configuration of the object graph) sets up a totally static set of dependencies once, then you might as well just make a tree of `new` calls instead of using a framework. If you need to do runtime hot-swapping or mutli-armed-bandit tests then you can win big with DI frameworks

Comment: (making a lot of assumptions about the capabilities of that framework, and how you can configure it of course :) )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> has no usable concept of interface based programming (as in C# interfaces)

Just because the compiler can't check that you're using the interface correctly doesn't mean there's "no usable concept of interfaces". You document an interface, and write unit tests.

As for globals, it's not like `public static` methods and fields on C# or Java classes are really any different. Consider how java.lang.Math works, for example. Now consider the fact that java.lang.Math **isn't** a Singleton. They did that for a good reason.

> With all these goodies is there really any point to a dependency injection container

I doubt it, but then I never really saw the point of them in C# or Java, either. Dependency injection is a programming **technique**, in my view. And there's really not that much to it, either.

> I have always suspected that Dependency injection as a design pattern was a bad smell that has been created by everything must be a class "Nazi thinking"

No, it isn't. Dependency injection is a good idea a lot of the time. You don't need a class to inject dependencies into, either. Every time you pass something to a free function as a parameter, instead of having the function call another function to get the information, you're basically doing the same thing: inversion of control. Python also lets you treat modules similarly to classes in a lot of ways (certainly more ways than Java and C# do). There are problems that can be solved by passing modules as parameters to functions. :)

> So far I think I can cover factories, Singletons, Multi-instance objects, just by using Globals.

Singletons are the bad smell, if anything. In nearly every case, in my extensive experience, they exist because someone thought it would be Bad(TM) on principle to have a global, without really thinking through the possible options, or why they wanted that kind of access to a single shared object, or even why globals are "Bad(TM) on principle" in the first place.

You **could** make a global function in Python that acts as a factory. However, I would say it's more Pythonic to do any of the following:

a) first, make really, really, **really** sure you can't just do what you want with `__init__`. I mean, in a dynamically typed language, you can do a heck of a lot that way.

b) If `__init__` won't cut it, try using `__new__` to control the behaviour.

In Python, classes are objects themselves, which are callable. By default, calling them instantiates the class. With `__new__`, you can hook into that.

c) Use a decorator applied to the class. Here is an example that makes a Singleton (just because):

```
def _singleton(cls):
  instance = cls()
  result = lambda: instance
  result.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
  return result

@_singleton
class example(object): pass
```

The way this works: when you decorate the class, `_singleton()` is called, with the class being passed in. An instance is constructed and cached, and `_singleton()` returns an anonymous function that will return the instance when called. To complete the charade, the class's documentation is attached to the anonymous function. Then Python rebinds the class' name in the global scope to the returned anonymous function. So when you call it, you get the same instance of the class, every time.

Now, this can still be worked around, of course (you can do something like `example().__class__()` to get another instance), but it's much more clear that you're doing something wrong than if you simply ignored a factory function in order to use the constructor normally. Plus, it means the calling code actually acts as if it were calling the constructor normally :)

> The Duck Typing is the thing that is getting me at the moment, so used to defining interfaces then basing classes on these interfaces and letting the static stuff cover my stupidity that I feel that without static typing, containers are a bit useless.

You need to shift your thinking: stop worrying about what the thing you've been passed **is**, and worry about *whether it can do what you want it to do*. That's how duck typing works.

Comment: There is a difference between dependency injection, and inversion of control. It is very slight but significant. Also you can not say that program decomposition (Normalized data, responsibilities, collaborations) are there for the purpose of inversion of control or that there has been thought about inversion of control, when decomposing your program into suitable structures. If you do think about inversion of control at design time, then your introducing programming artifacts of a language environment into pure design in my humble opinion :)

Comment: Second read, Unit Tests and documentation to enforce interfaces? I thought the whole point of duck typing is that if it looks like a duck and talks like a duck then we call it a duck. If you enforce this tight coupling of abstraction through interfaces as you have described, then your throwing away one of the things I love about Python which is dynamic typing.

Comment: Isn't a Dependency Injection Framework a Singleton class by design?

Comment: Public Static is a lot different from a Global object. A Global object can be reassigned at run-time. A Static class or a Static anything in C# can not.

Comment: +1 for such a lengthy prose though, it is much appreciated and I think the argumentative approach does make you focus about the question you have asked, even if it does not directly answer the question.

Comment: "Unit Tests and documentation to enforce interfaces? I thought the whole point of duck typing is that if it looks like a duck and talks like a duck then we call it a duck." Yes; and documentation is how you make sure everyone knows how ducks walk and quack; and unit tests are how you observe a duck-candidate. I have no idea what you mean by "tight coupling of abstraction through interfaces". Well-designed interfaces reduce coupling and improve cohesion. You can make good - or bad - interfaces in any language.

Comment: I'm unaware of anything in C# that prevents you from assigning to a `static` field of a class. `readonly` exists for a reason. As for DI frameworks, like I said I don't bother with them, so I don't really know or care how they're designed. The point is you don't need a DI framework to do DI.

Comment: "tight coupling of abstraction through interfaces". What I mean is that if you implement an interface in a language like c# then your making a promise not only to fellow programmers, but also to the compiler, that you will comply to the interface, therefore there will be no surprises.

Comment: Would I use Python on a large scale project, heck no. The fact that your promises are made through documentation alone makes it a very hard language to architect against. I have just been using the AsyncCore stuff, I came across a method that accepts a function of a certain signature. The only way I could work out the signature was to look at the Documentation. In C#, I can usually guess my way through most of it, and if there is anything exotic, I look it up, or the compiler yells at me to stop hitting it with rubbish.

Comment: "Well-designed interfaces reduce coupling and improve cohesion". Here lies the problem. You can not seriously design an interface in Python. I just read a good article which described python/ruby as play doh and Java/C# as LEGO bricks. It is far easier to reason over programming designs when your dealing with defined shapes as in LEGO than it is in Play doh. Thanks, I think through this discussion you have cleared up where I am getting problems with python and why.

Comment: As for the comment about C#, to be honest I avoid static like the plague and singletons at all cost. They kill scalability. Your right about the static field being able to be assigned a new value. I was thinking about static factory patterns and redefining class methods on the hoof. This whole switch to dynamic is warping my fragile little mind :)

Comment: The last paragraph really says everything I can about the philosophy here. Pythonistas believe they can and do "seriously design interfaces" on a regular basis; their concept of an interface is presumably quite different from yours.

Comment: Been thinking about the comment about reassigning of Statics in C# compared to globals. A Global in Python can have its entire type definition redefined at run time, a static in C# can not. That is what I was trying to say earlier, but failed dismally :).

Answer (score 10):

### The conclusion

(The following is the most relevant part of the original post. I admit, I waxed a little poetical, and so I though I should simply include the most important sentences in their own section. That said, I feel that the poetic waxing is important enough that I have not deleted it.)

Dependency injection is still used. There will always be the need for objects to communicate with already instantiated objects. There will be a need for "parent" objects (or containers, or whatever) to set up the state of their "children". These will need to be passed in through some method or set through some assignment, but in the abstract sense, it is the same thing.

### The original answer:

#### Type systems

Python is, in many ways, the second most mathematically pure language I've ever encountered -- it follows only Scheme (though I've not ever used Haskell, I understand that to be up there too).

Python supports closures natively, it has continuations (yield syntax), multiple inheritance, and a loop comprehension syntax which is largely unparalleled. All of these bring it far closer to Alonzo Church's original vision in Lambda Calculus (an McCarthy's original ideas behind Lisp). Python 3 makes it even more pure with set comprehensions (which make my heart flutter just thinking of their inherent beauty).

Constantly and continually there is the idea that the data stored in the variables of Python have more in common with their counterparts in Mathematics, so much that the interface of an object can be diminished to simply be, "the adjectives or set of adjectives which describe the object". Basically, an object's interface is wholly and completely contained in its `__dict__` and displayed with `dir`.

All of that considered, it does start making one wonder whether the "traditional" way of looking at things ("traditional" with quotes because Python is as old as Java) really can work in such a language. When even arguments lists in Python have an OOP feeling to them (kwargs, anyone?) it really does turn the world upside-down.

Dependency injection is still used. There will always be the need for objects to communicate with already instantiated objects. There will be a need for "parent" objects (or containers, or whatever) to set up the state of their "children". These will need to be passed in through some method or set through some assignment, but in the abstract sense, it is the same thing. But there is an implicit trust that the contents of the passed object's `__dict__` will contain an appropriate description. Because of this, it becomes far less, "once I have instantiated this object, I will bestow upon it the very things needed for the life," and far more, "Well, yea, an object needs a state, so I'm giving it one."

And this exposes a hidden aspect of static typing. In order for something which expects an `IFoo` to work, it has to have full and complete knowledge of what it means to be an `IFoo`, even if it will never need 90% of that definition. Meanwhile, duck typing makes the depending object know only that properties X, Y, and Z should be there at run-time.

#### Globals

As to globals. Avoid them unless you have no other choice. You are better off using a Singleton if only because Singletons allow you to log when the value changes. This is not true of globals.

There is a rule of programming, the more exposed and complicated your interface, the harder it will be to maintain. If something is placed in a global variable, *anything* in that module, and possibly *anything* in ***ANY*** module can modify the value. The code can almost become non-deterministic. I assure you, sadness follows.

Comment: like your style of prose. I need to read it with appreciation before I can evaluate it :)

Comment: Haskell is great, although my maths is poor. I struggled with Monads. I get monoids but Monads still elude me after 2 years :) F# is a great compromise. I personally like Python because it looks like pseudo code.

Comment: Can you explain the __Dict__ begin exposed through DIR, I never come across this.

Comment: Not too sure about the container Class, hierarchy stuff. The beauty of being able to access Global Variables is that the need for a container disappears as your environment becomes the container. Yes it does require immense discipline, but so far I think that dynamic programming in general requires a lot more discipline that static programming. Its a lot less forgiving when things go wrong :)

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers Discipline is easiest if we make it harder to misbehave ;-)

Comment: "I assure you, sadness follows."  Can I use that?