# Is there a point to dependency injection container in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, frameworks

I'm a long time back-end developer but recently I have managed to develop some medium sized one-page web-app.

On server side I have worked with many modern frameworks like Spring, Grails, Symfony, [Silex](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/), Slim and other and I really liked the concept of micro-framework of Silex or Slim (in all case MVC frameworks).

On client side, due the different application nature I think [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) is the best approach.

Quickly evaluating some micro JS framework ([riot](http://riotjs.com/), [backbone](http://backbonejs.org)) and comparing to my server side background I have noted that in JS Frameworks the Dependency injection Container (DIC) is not considered a fundamental part of a framework (micro frameworks at least).

On every server side mordern [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (Micro)Framework the DIC is the foundation of the framework but I don't see this happen on Javascript Frameworks (micro frameworks at least, I know heavy fat Angular have it).

From my searches the only standalone DIC container for JS with some followers is [bottlejs](https://github.com/young-steveo/bottlejs)
that has only 672 Stars on GitHub. Comparing this to PHP where there are many standalone DIC projects, for example [Pimple](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple) (1570 Stars) or [PHP-DI](https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI) (1040 Stars) you can see a great disparity

Do you think is a critical mistake or subvalutation that many js micro-framework do?
Or the modularity, testability  and mantainability of DIC is achievable in other way in JS.

Comment: I don't think this question is suited for SO. Maybe - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was unaware of softwareengineering existence. Indeed in stack overflow there is a similar question related to python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880884/is-there-a-point-to-dependency-injection-container-in-python

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Personally I also think the question isn't fit for SO (could be quite opinion based). There are however frameworks who have it built in, for example AngularJs does it. Is it necessary for JS, I don't think so, I think the majority of frameworks don't have it built in because of minification issues

Comment: Comparing GH stars is pointless. PHP DI projects are 5+ years. JS projects aren't. Singletons can be naturally produced with JS modules, so this isn't a concern for DI. And testability is achievable with JS module mocking, too (proxyquire, etc). This is what some frameworks (notably React-like) rely on.

Comment: @estus I was unware of [modules singletons pattern](https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern). But this pattern can give you the abilitiy to replace a sub-dependecies in a in imported model like DIC do? If in my new file I import singleton instance A from module M1, and M1 depends on singleton instance B form M2 (import {B} form "M2"). Can I override that dependencies before it's instantiated? I think this is really important for code reuse. I see proxyquire can do it for testing but I don't think is applicable for modular application production code nor for ES6 Modules.

Comment: Using DI in a language that isn't type safe doesn't seem necessary... would be more useful for typescript...

Comment: Doing some research I think that traditional DIC an IOC in javascript can be optimized and implemented using the modules sigletons pattern together with the (non standard, work in progress) [ES module loaders](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader).

Answer (score 0):

Singletons can be naturally produced with JS modules, so this isn't a concern for DI. And testability is achievable with JS module mocking, too (proxyquire, etc). This is what some frameworks (Durandal, React-like) rely on.

In testing rig ES6 modules usually use require under the hood any way, so the method is still applicable. `proxyquire` and other cache-mangling libraries may have their limitations (deep dependencies), but in well-written test you usually mock the units one level higher, so this generally works. This is how this is done in Jest internally, which is conventionally used to test React and React-like.

So this depends on what these 'micro-frameworks' really are. As for current-gen macro-frameworks, React is supposed to not need DIC (also, it isn't opinionated, it's developer's responsibility to extend it's functionality). While Angular, Aurelia, Ember, Polymer and Vue 2 feature DIC - because it generally benefits application design.

Comment: If I'm right React and Vue2 are View Only Component Frameworks, they are not Application Framework so if they are usong DI it is probably limitated to the View management not the whole application. Or not? –

Comment: Vue is componentized, so is React. It depends on the point of view what's considered a framework and what's a library. Among the mentioned ones Backbone is certainly less 'framework'. DI usefulness doesn't depend on the language (Angular 1). But it can benefit from language features (Angular 2+ & TS).